# How to add properties to a .bak file which might be visible when we right click and is visible?

Tags: winforms

On file system is it possible to add meta properties (the properties that appears when we right click on a file and are visible in properties tab) to a .BAK file programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You need to read the meta data of the file and then create a .BAK file to write them programatically.

Comment: Have tried it but was not helpful.
Apart from that tried few external dll(s) provided by Microsoft itself,but when i move file from NTFS to FAT32 system or drives it results in loss of my properties.